# Change standard invoice address in checkout

Tags: checkout, billing-address

When customer add a new invoice address in checkout, this new address will be add as new address but ist not the standard for the next order. This is inconvenient, because normaly the invoice address only change after relocation.

How can I change the process, so that the last added invoice address is the standard for the next purchase?